# How to add multiple view controllers on scrollview without them overlapping

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to fit multiple view controllers on a scroll view. But the views overlap on the screen

```
    let settingView: SettingsView = SettingsView(nibName: "SettingsView", bundle: nil)
    self.addChild(settingView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(settingView.view)
    settingView.didMove(toParent: self)
    settingView.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    let mainView: MainView = MainView(nibName: "MainView", bundle: nil)
    self.addChild(mainView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(mainView.view)
    mainView.didMove(toParent: self)
    mainView.view.frame = self.view.bounds

    var mainFrame: CGRect = mainView.view.frame
    mainFrame.origin.x = settingView.view.frame.width
    mainView.view.frame = mainFrame

    let connectionView: ConnectionView = ConnectionView(nibName: "ConnectionView", bundle: nil)
    self.addChild(connectionView)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(connectionView.view)
    connectionView.didMove(toParent: self)
    connectionView.view.frame = scrollView.bounds

    var connectionFrame: CGRect = connectionView.view.frame
    connectionFrame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
    connectionView.view.frame = connectionFrame


    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (self.scrollView.frame.size.width) * 3
        , height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: (self.view.frame.width), y: self.view.frame.height)
```

each view controller should fit the size of the screen but they overlap onto each other screen

Comment: Are you sure you can't do what you need with just a single Table View? Adding multiple VCs to a single screen is usually not advised.

Comment: @RussJ I am trying to do a snapchat type of simulation and I've looked up tutorials and most of them consisted of using a scroll view which I've done but when I have multiple screens, none of the viewcontrollers fits the screen size. They are usually smaller or bigger than the screen on the scrollview

Comment: What specifically are you trying to simulate from Snapchat?

Comment: @RussJ The change between views like messages, camera, and explore or something like snap does

Comment: Ohhh ok. Well in my opinion, you will probably be better off just having separate view controllers (not on the same page) and simply do transitions between them. I would bet good money that is how Snap is set up as well.

Comment: You could use ContainerViews